# dpkg not working the same way when invoked from Dockerfile or within the container

Tags: docker, dpkg

I have a Dockerfile describing a container used to build some libs.
Basically, it looks like this:

```
FROM debian:stretch-slim

COPY somedebianrepo/*.deb \
     /basedir/

RUN dpkg -i /basedir/*.deb
```

When I build the image, I get :

> dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of *[one of my lib]* ... depends on *[some other lib]* however *[some other lib]* is not installed

Which may sound obvious... but : when I comment the RUN line :

```
# RUN dpkg -i /basedir/*.deb
```

then build the image, start the container, and connect to it, I expected the dpkg command to act the same... But actually, when I launch directly the command works fine with no such error.

```
root@host$ docker exec -it -u root <mycontainer> bash
root@mycontainer $ dpkg -i /basedir/*.deb
root@mycontainer $ (no error)
```

I also tried with apt-get install, and also encountered such different behaviors.

Since I am quite newbie with Docker, the answer may be quite obvious... but still, it is not to me! I expected the commands executed through "RUN" to act the same way as if executed from within the container..
So if anyone could point out me where I am wrong, she/he is welcome!

**EDIT 1** : I have tried to run apt-get update before the dpkg command, though I did not expect it to work : with no success

Comment: try to run `apt update` before

Comment: I did unsucessflully. I should have mentioned : my bad

Comment: try to use the image `debian:stretch`

Comment: I have no choice on the image I start from, unfortunately. I have to make it work with this one!

Comment: why? :-D ... at least try that, and then you will now if your packages are bad or the image is bad...

Comment: Do you have anything after `RUN ...` in the docker file?

Comment: @MazelTov I understand your point (even though I already used that image with success with other builds) : unfortunately, it failed. the same way

Comment: @Andremoniy Yes, I used to have a few things : mainly some user/groups conf, and a few CMDs . Though, they are currently commented for the purpose of my test